# How to get back into the game after your lane opponent is up kills/farm/level

Tags: league-of-legends

Sometimes I play a game where I end up being out farmed and leveled.  Of course this rarely happens to me but it does happens once in a while.  What is the best way to make a come back?

**Things I have thought of**

Get two GP10 items to build your money since you cant farm as well anyways.

Ask your jungle to baby sit you.. although this will take away from the jungles farm/levels.

Build lane resistances and buy more health potions.

Has anyone else encountered this? What have you done?

Answer (score 3):

Getting GP10 items might be a good idea, but you're already behind and farming under your turret, missing those last hits because you have no AD might hurt you more than it helps. Keep in mind GP10 items take at least 20mins to pay for themselves alone if you don't sell them (and 10 if you do).

Asking for help from the jungler is definetly a good idea, but even if you do get the kill you'll only clear a wave or so of minions before he comes back with even more items from all the gold he got off you.

Additional measures include giving golems to your top, trying to counter-jungle to make up for a bit of the deficit (especially effective if their jungler is breathing down your neck all game and is out of position to defend his jungle).

What I see happening in pro games when for example top is outmatched is they just give up on it. I mean no ganks, the guy sits under the tower getting last hits when he can, otherwise just trying to soak xp without getting hit/feeding more. The jungler tries to make up for it by ganking the other lanes instead and feeding his AP/AD carries, and once the top tower falls (and it will), the top guy will roam and try to help gank.

Keep in mind, after a point extra gold won't do much for you anymore. Once you have your core items, and a few "luxury items" as Dota players call them, the rest isn't as big a deal. If you keep playing and keep farming, you'll equalize eventually. Don't sacrifice more than you have to for towers, try to be aggressive about getting the dragon, and most importantly don't feed any more for any reason.

Answer (score 2):

This heavily depends on who you are versus who they are, if you have any form of CC try to lure them into a tower dive and CC them and kite them around until your tower helps with the kill, of course if your going against say a shyvana that won't work because if with CC her burnout combined with a possible ult factoring in that you're already behind in farm and probably levels means she will be able to pick you up tower or no tower.

Alert the jungler to your situation and ask for a gank, if it's successful just farm up until they get back and then tower camp and remind your jungler you need help, rinse and repeat until you are as farmed as they are and can handle your lane again.  If not even the jungler can help you have to face facts, your tower is going to go down, now if you want to give them a few kills with the tower that's up to you, once your tower has fallen both you and the other top will probably start roaming, and that's your chance to pick up some kills / assists going into the late game.

In conclusion though your jungler should be able to help you enough to fix your lane, assuming you tell him at a decent time, don't wait till you've died 6 or 7 times to ask for help, 1-2 deaths max before asking for assistance.